# ros package path

Tags: ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am using ros tutorials to understand ros i am stuck in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH how to create it or what to do with it i am bit confused about it kindly help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27934/ros-package-path/) by [danish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1766/danish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you had a look at this page http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables? If you just want to quickly compile a bunch of example,  do

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`
```

in the folder where you have kept the tutorial packages. Otherwise, the tutorials are very comprehensive usually.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2012-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1766/danish/) on 2012-02-20**:
for ROS_PACKAGE_PATH i have tp paste the same command as it is or have to make same changes "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/user/ros/ros-pkg:/another/path"

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2013-03-04**:
When I try to add in groovy another path like

`export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH: pwd` 
after reopening the termianl or in a new tab, the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH does not contains the earlier added path.  Why?

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2013-03-04**:
I found out, i must put in my ~/.bashrc at the end the above mentioned code